# Phantom Table being created in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm using Teradata 16.20.05.01 to run the following script:

```sql
create table t1(v int not null);
create table t2(w int null);
alter table t1 add constraint pk primary key (v);
alter table t2 add constraint t2_fk foreign key (w) references t1 (v);
```

After adding the foreign key, I suddenly get one excess table in my schema:

```sql
select TableName, RequestText
from "DBC".Tables
where DatabaseName = 'test'
and (TableName like 't1%' or TableName like 't2%')
```

Output:

```
TableName |RequestText                                                           |
----------|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
t1        |alter table t1 add constraint pk primary key (v)                      |
t2        |create table t2(w int null)                                           |
T2_0      |alter table t2 add constraint t2_fk foreign key (w) references t1 (v) |
```

This is especially annoying when re-creating that foreign key:

```sql
alter table t2 drop constraint t2_fk;
alter table t2 add constraint t2_fk foreign key (w) references t1 (v);
```

Which isn't possible because of:

> SQL Error [5303] [HY000]: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.33] [Error 5303] [SQLState HY000] Error table 'TEST.t2_0' already exists.

#### Workaround:

The problem does not appear when using inline constraint definitions

```sql
create table t1(v int not null, constraint pk primary key (v));
create table t2(w int null, constraint t2_fk foreign key (w) references t1 (v));
```

Is this a known issue? Is there a reliable workaround?

Comment: I guess that if you add `WITH NO CHECK OPTION` there should be no additional table: `alter table t2 add constraint t2_fk foreign key (w) references WITH NO CHECK OPTION t1 (v);`

Comment: @lad2025: You're right, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented behaviour, when you add a Foreign Key to an existing table there's an error table created and all all rows violating the constraint are copied into it. And it's not dropped automatically after the ALTER.

The workaround is simple: Don't use Standard Foreign Keys, you will hardly find any site using it. Switch to Batch FKs, i.e. `REFERENCES WITH CHECK OPTION`, which applies the check on a request level (not row by row), or to a Soft/Dummy FK, `REFERENCES WITH NO CHECK OPTION`, which simply defined the constraint without enforcing it (you must check for PK/FK violations in your load scripts anyway).